# How to queue calls for a function

Tags: c#, queue, thread-safety

I am communicating with a I/O relay board over serial bus. The board is controlled and queried using byte commands. My goal is to have a `backgroundworker` periodically assessing the states of the relays and inputs and updating the GUI whilst running a "script" which carries out a series of actions on the board.

I have two functions which transmit and receive the commands to the board. My issue is that if I run my "script" whilst using a `backgroundworker` to update the GUI I start getting read and write failures - I am assuming because both processes are accessing the same function within a short space of time.

```
static SerialPort USB_PORT;
byte[] SerBuf = new byte[64];
byte usb_found = 0;
byte states = 0;

private void transmit(byte write_bytes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (usb_found == 1) USB_PORT.Write(SerBuf, 0, write_bytes);      // writes specified amount of SerBuf out on COM port
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                usb_found = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("write fail");
                return;
            }
        }

private void receive(byte read_bytes)
        {
            byte x;
            for (x = 0; x < read_bytes; x++)       // this will call the read function for the passed number times, 
            {                                      // this way it ensures each byte has been correctly recieved while
                try                                // still using timeouts
                {
                    if (usb_found == 1) USB_PORT.Read(SerBuf, x, 1);     // retrieves 1 byte at a time and places in SerBuf at position x
                }
                catch (Exception)                                       // timeout or other error occured, set lost comms indicator
                {
                    usb_found = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("read fail");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to 'queue' any and all calls to these two functions so the entire function completes before the next one begins?

Comment: are those functions called from `background worker` ?

Comment: [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement?  Make sure you don't lock while on the main UI thread...

Comment: @Tigran - both the 'script' and the `backgroundworker` will call the functions

Comment: @Idle_Mind - never seen these `lock` statements before. Do I put the statement wherever I call the function?

Comment: You'd create an object at class level that the lock statement acquires.  Then, INSIDE the function(s), you wrap all the existing code inside the lock statement.  Now when multiple threads try to run the same method, only the first one will acquire the lock object and run.  All the other threads will wait until the lock is released, then a different thread (indeterminate) will acquire the lock and run.

Comment: @Idle_Mind. something like this?
````
static readonly object _Lock = new object();
private void transmit(byte write_bytes)
        {
            lock (_Lock)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (usb_found == 1) USB_PORT.Write(SerBuf, 0, write_bytes); 
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    usb_found = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("write fail");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }````

Comment: @Idle_Mind the above code seems to have worked! many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by @Idle_Mind, I created an object and then used a lock statement to prevent access from two different threads. It seems to have worked!

```
static readonly object _Lock = new object();
private void transmit(byte write_bytes)
        {
            lock (_Lock)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (usb_found == 1) USB_PORT.Write(SerBuf, 0, write_bytes);      // writes specified amount of SerBuf out on COM port
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    usb_found = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("write fail");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

private void receive(byte read_bytes)
        {
            lock (_Lock)
            {
                byte x;
                for (x = 0; x < read_bytes; x++)       // this will call the read function for the passed number times, 
                {                                      // this way it ensures each byte has been correctly recieved while
                    try                                // still using timeouts
                    {
                        if (usb_found == 1) USB_PORT.Read(SerBuf, x, 1);     // retrieves 1 byte at a time and places in SerBuf at position x
                    }
                    catch (Exception)                                       // timeout or other error occured, set lost comms indicator
                    {
                        usb_found = 0;
                        MessageBox.Show("read fail");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```